# TcpListener and TcpClient on the same machine

Tags: c#, tcp

I've got TcpListener and TcpClient on the same machine. TcpListener started in server program and client program connects to the server using ConnectAsync() method. And connects with success. Great! But... The server program didn't implement any AcceptTcpClient() method. So - how the client managed to connect to the server in this case and how to handle it?

Comment: How do you know it was a success? Have you checked the top client.Connected state?

Comment: tcpClient.Connected = true Connect() method in the client 

And I expected that Connect() method in the client will wait until AcceptTcpClient() methods on server is used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a backlog queue of connections being accepted. This is the optional number in the `Start(int)` method on the server. Your client is "connected" at the network layer, even if your app hasn't taken charge of that connection yet.

Comment: Question regarding it... The client thinks that it connected to the server (tcpClient.Connected = true) and starts sending data to the server which cannot accept it in fact.. So....??
In fact this question came when I started using the client and the server on the same machine - before when I run client and server on different machine I didn't face with this case

Comment: @IgorManowar the client never talks directly to your  app - there are buffers in the network stack and hardware at both ends. Your client is sending to those buffers. Eventually they will fill up and your client will hit back-pressure.

Comment: @IgorManowar you say "can't accept it" - yes it can; at any moment your server can accept the connection (which really just means: get a hook in managed code), and start reading the buffers - no data has been lost

Comment: It's more clear now) Thanks a lot!